# Replace even words with appropriate number of "*"

Tags: linux, bash

I need to input some number of lines, replace all words on even spots of lines with the appropriate number of "*" and output the result to the screen.

For example, the input:

```
Hi! How are you? 

It's been a while since we've met.
```

will give us:

```
Hi! *** are ****

It's **** a ***** since ***** met.
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

res=""

mm="*"

i=0

while IFS= read -r line; do 

for word in line

do

tmp=""

lng=${#word}

if [ $(($lng % 2)) -eq 0 ]; 

then

while [ $i -lt $lng ]; do

tmp=$tmp$mm

let i=i+1

done

res+=${tmp}

else

res+=${word}

fi

done

done

echo -e "${res}"
```

But it doesn't do what it's supposed to(

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes could do this easily with `awk` or`sed` rather than shell. Could you please do post sample input and expected output more clearly so that we could have clear picture of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a perl one-liner:

```
$ echo "Hi! How are you?\nIt's been a while since we've met." \
   | perl -pe 's/\S+\s+\K(\S+)/"*" x length($1)/eg'
Hi! *** are ****
It's **** a ***** since ***** met.
```

Basically, for each pair of whitespace separated words, replace the second one with a number of asterisks equal to its length.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. Provide all words in `BEGIN` section's `split` function which you want to get substituted with `*`.

```
awk 'BEGIN{  
   num=split("hi,hello,bla",arr,",")
   for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
     array[arr[i]]
   }
}
{
  for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){
    val=length($j)
    if($j in array){ 
      $j=sprintf("%0"val"d","")
      gsub(/0/,"*",$j)
    }
  }
}
1
' Input_file
```